# React - child elements not rerendering

Tags: reactjs

I'm pretty new to react, and not understanding why my child elements are not rerendering when state is changed.  Everything works fine until you hit add-column-button.  This changes the heck out of board in state, and indeed board seems to rerender, but columns do not.

```
const Board = function() {

  const [board, setBoard] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(boardJSON);
    setBoard(boardJSON.board);
  }, [])

  const addColumn = () => {
    console.log('addColumn');
    let inx = board.length + 1;
    let col = {userId: 1, columnId: inx, header: 'Bob', cards: []};
    board.push(col);
    board[0].header = "Marge";
    let cardx = {"cardId": 4, "desc": "Break sound barrier", "status": "incomplete"};
    board[0].cards.push(cardx);
    board[1].cards[1].status = "destroyed";
    setBoard(board);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="board">
      {console.log("parent rerendering", board) // we get this far, but columns don't rerender          
      }
      {board.map((column) => (
        <Column key={column.columnId} column={column} />
        ))}
      </div>
      <button className="add-column-button" onClick={() => {addColumn()}}>
        <img src={plus_sm} />
        Add new column
      </button>
      {console.log("we got to the end", board) // did we get to the end?
      }
    </div>
  );
};

export default Board;
```

Here is what I got on the console.  Nothing changes on the screen after addColumn, and we don't get the "rendering column" messages.  Just seems to skip right over the remap.

```
parent rerendering Array(0)
Board.js:42 we got to the end Array(0)
Board.js:11 Object
Board.js:31 parent rerendering Array(2)
Board.js:42 we got to the end Array(2)
Column.js:21 rendering column number 1
Column.js:21 rendering column number 2
Column.js:10 column rendering, props received Object
Column.js:10 column rendering, props received Object
Board.js:16 addColumn
Board.js:31 parent rerendering (3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
Board.js:42 we got to the end (3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
```

In case you're wondering, this is a react-dnd app, but I took all the dnd out in case that was causing the problem.  It wasn't.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you mutate the state. See this [link](https://daveceddia.com/why-not-modify-react-state-directly/) on why not to modify react state directly. Also see [this example](https://codesandbox.io/s/vigilant-khorana-g1c7n?file=/src/App.js) that I made to give you the idea what will happen if you directly changed the state.

In your case it should be:

```
const addColumn = () => {
    console.log('addColumn');
    let inx = board.length + 1;
    let col = {userId: 1, columnId: inx, header: 'Bob', cards: []};

    const newBoardContent = [...board];

    newBoardContent.push(col);
    newBoardContent[0].header = "Marge";
    let cardx = {"cardId": 4, "desc": "Break sound barrier", "status": "incomplete"};
    newBoardContent[0].cards.push(cardx);
    newBoardContent[1].cards[1].status = "destroyed";
    setBoard(newBoardContent);
};
```

Comment: Don't know how I missed that; works great; thanks much.